Black screen after switching to wayland
After going to the login screen on KDE and switching from x11 to Wayland, after entering my password, the screen just goes black and stays like that. The weird thing is that I thought I was using Wayland before, I have no idea when it switched or even if it did switch honestly.
System info:
Operating System: Manjaro Linux 
KDE Plasma Version: 6.0.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.4.0
Qt Version: 6.7.2
Kernel Version: 6.10.0-3-MANJARO (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor
Memory: 31.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2


It was a NVIDIA issue of course, this solution worked for me:
https://forums.opensuse.org/t/solution-to-nvidia-drm-failed-to-grab-modeset-ownership/148509
In summary, it said edit the /etc/default/grub file to include the text nvidia-drm.modeset=1 in the string following this line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=, so in the end it should look something like GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nvidia-drm.modeset=1" (through there may be other strings in that line so just include a space between the text you add and the already existing text if there is some).
After doing so, update your grub configuration which you can do using the sudo update-grub on Manjaro or sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg on OpenSUSE.
